# MKMapView renders map at very low quality

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I'm using MKMapView to display a map on my iOS app. I've simulated my location to London for the sake of example as I know it has high quality aerial imagery.

Here is a picture from Apple's own Maps app. No problems, super quality:

[image]

Here is the same place from my app at the approximately same zoom level:

[image]

It looks like it's zoomed out, cropped and zoomed into that region as satellite image is from a more "zoomed out" zoom level. At that level, all the labels disappear too (in Maps), but I've got the labels. I've got multiple instances of MKMapView and the problem is present on all of them. I don't have any special filters, scaling, or anything that would affect the rendering of the maps. In other words, the view instances themselves aren't "zoomed in" in any way. What is exactly going on and how can I make MKMapView render the map at the quality where Maps renders it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **MKMapTypeSatellite** type map, consider that this type has been abandoned by Apple.
Try using **MKMapTypeSatelliteFlyover** or **MKMapTypeHybridFlyover** for a better quality.

Comment: Just looked at the documentation and `MKMapTypeSatellite` doesn't appear to be deprecated, but the options you mentioned do appear to be new as of iOS 9. https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmaptype?language=objc